# How to stop / hijack a infinite redirection loop with a redirecting rule

Tags: 7, rules, redirection

I'm using Rules and Detector module to prevent IE < 7.0 users from browsing the site.

I've setted up a rule, executed when UA (Detector) properties are loaded. Dependings on user agent value, the rule have an action, which consists in redirecting user to a particuler node (explanation).

This works well, so well that redirection is always active, even on my destination node. So it lead me to kind of 'Too much redirection error'.

I don't manage to put another condition, like Path has url alias; that will prevent all undesired redirections.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
Please, don't hesitate to suggest me another way to achieve this redirection properly.

Comment: It's none of my business but it seems a bit harsh to exclude a whole section of users from your site based on using a browser that they might have no choice but to use. Many large corporates are stuck with legacy software because of the sheer cost of upgrading (until at least a year or so ago Sky Sports forced the use of IE6 internally for example), and you're alienating all of those. Why not take a softer, more educational approach, like that offered by the [jReject module](http://drupal.org/project/jreject)? Like I said, none of my business, but I think it bears consideration

Comment: Indeed it's an internal requierment. Legacies browsers MUST NOT evolve, because they deal with old sites/apps (IE 6 and 7), and this new site a full rebranding, which needs full CSS3 support. So, even if I'd general prefer to let users decide, in this case I really have to prevent and catch their attention :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider a simple redirect in .htaccess

To redirect based on user agent, if not already on redirected page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE [1-7]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/upgrade/
RewriteRule .? upgrade [L]
```

Comment: Indeed, I did not even think about this ... I was focused on Drupal features ... Well it's not really what I'm looking for, but it would help me as a good workaround. Thanks to think outside of the box :)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able, for mysterious reasons, to implement David Thomas solutions.
So I decided to write a really dirty solution :

Assuming that I have an existing node with "upgrade" alias :

### page.tpl.php

```html
<!--[if lt IE 9]>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     if (window.location.pathname != "/upgrade") {
        window.location.pathname = "/upgrade"
     }
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Once again, it's quite dirty:

- conditions are only available for IE
- it's static and imply to deliver this additional code (would be quite better with configuration / module)
- I must have and existing node (not too much important).

I'm really not proud of myself, but you know ... client is requiring this feature RIGHT NOW ! I hope I'll have time to found a better solution later (at least, it's planned).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try - not sure if it'll help in your case but it has worked for me.

Add /#r=off after every link in mobile that links to the main site (desktop);

i.e. http://yoursite.com/#r=off

This will direct you to your main site while preventing redirect back to mobile.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking time quite a long moment after. Indeed it's a little bit far from my needs.